# Phoenix: how to include bower-installed .js?

Tags: bower, phoenix-framework, brunch

I've installed a bower package through Brunch into a Phoenix app. How do I include the .js files from that package into my application? The package installs into `/bower_components`—do I need to add that somewhere to build it? Or is there a helper for me to include the js in each layout manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here's](https://nickstalter.com/adding-bower-components-to-phoenix.html) an answer for anyone hunting for this:

If you've installed your package simply expose the folder:

```
plug Plug.Static,
  at: "/", from: :discovery, gzip: false,
  only: ~w(css fonts images js favicon.ico robots.txt bower_components)
```

That's after adding your package to `bower.json` and adding the folder to `.bowerrc`.

Comment: Note: the `bower_components` folder must be in `web/static/assets` for this to work; you can set it with `.bowerrc`.